# How to handle onclick event in a listview button?

Tags: asp.net, listview, onclick

If I have listview control with a button in the item template, how do I handle the onclick events for each of the buttons that ends up getting generated in the listview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **CommandArgument** property of the button control to specify which button clicked.

[This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx) shows how to get values from command argument within listview control.

Answer (score 0):

Same way you do with every other button:

```
<asp:Button ID="templateButton" runat="server" OnClick="templateButton_OnClick"/>
```

Except that you will need to determine which button was clicked in the handler itself.

```
protected void templateButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button myButton = (Button)sender;
}
```